# Variable for file directory path not being recognized

Tags: php, html, image

so far I've successfully moved an uploaded image to its designated directory and stored the file path of the moved image into a database I have.

Problem is, however, is that the `img src` I have echoed fails to read the variable containing the file path of the image. I've been spending time verifying the validity of my variables, the code syntax in echoing the `img src`, and the successful execution of the move/storing code, but I still get `<img src=''` when I refer to the view source of the page that is supposed to display the file path contained in the variable.

I believe the file path is stored within the variable because the variable was able to be recognized by the functions that both moved the image to a directory and the query to database.

My coding and troubleshooting experience is still very adolescent, thus pardon me if the nature of my question is bothersomely trivial.

Before asking this question, I've searched for questions within SOF but none of the answers directly addressed my issue (of the questions I've searched at least).

**Main PHP Block**

```
  //assigning post values to simple variables
        $location = $_POST['avatar'];
                    .
                    .
                    .

  //re-new session variables to show most recent entries
        $_SESSION["avatar"] = $location;
                    .
                    .
                    .

  if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"])) {

        //define variables relevant to image uploading
             $type = explode('.', $_FILES["avatar"]["name"]);
             $type = $type[count($type)-1];
             $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
             $rdn = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 15);
        //check image size
             if($_FILES["avatar"]["size"] > 6500000) {
               echo"Image must be below 6.5 MB.";
               unlink($_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"]);
               exit();
             }
       //if image passes size check continue
             else {
               $location = "user_data/user_avatars/$rdn/".uniqid(rand()).'.'.$type;
               mkdir("user_data/user_avatars/$rdn/");
               move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"], $location);
           }

           }
           else {
             $location = "img/default_pic.jpg";
           }
```

**HTML Block**

```
              <div class="profileImage">
                <?php

                  echo "<img src='".$location."' class='profilePic' id='profilePic'/>";

                ?><br />
                  <input type="file" name="avatar" id="avatar" accept=".jpg,.png,.jpeg"/>
                    .
                    .
                    .
```

**View Source**

```
<div class="profileImage">
                <img src='' class='profilePic' id='profilePic'/><br />
                  <input type="file" name="avatar" id="avatar" accept=".jpg,.png,.jpeg"/>
                    .
                    .
                    .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I've finally found the error and was able to successfully solve it!

Simply declare a avatar session variable to the `$location` variable after updating the table, update the html insert by replacing all `$location` variables with `$_SESSION["avatar_column"]` and you are set!

**PHP:**

```
    $updateCD = "UPDATE users SET languages=?, interests=?, hobbies=?, bio=?, personal_link=?, country=?, avatar=? WHERE email=?";
  $updateST = $con->prepare($updateCD);
  $updateST->bind_param('ssssssss', $lg, $it, $hb, $bio, $pl, $ct, $location, $_SESSION["email_login"]);
  $updateST->execute();

  $_SESSION["avatar"] = $location;   //Important!

  if ($updateST->errno) {
      echo "FAILURE!!! " . $updateST->error;
      }
```

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="profileImage">
                <?php
                $_SESSION["avatar"] = (empty($_SESSION["avatar"])) ? "img/default_pic.jpg" : $_SESSION["avatar"] ;
                 echo "<img src='".$_SESSION["avatar"]."' class= 'profilePic' id='profilePic'> ";
                 ?>
        .
        .
        .
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','on');  

$location = ""; //path

if($_POST && $_FILES)
{
  if(is_uploaded_file())
  {

       // your code

      if(<your condition >)
      {
      }
      else
       {
        $location = "./user_data/user_avatars/".$rdn."/".uniqid(rand()).'.'.$type;

        if(!is_dir("./user_data/user_avatars/".$rdn."/"))
        {
           mkdir("./user_data/user_avatars/".$rdn."/",0777,true);
        }
        move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"], $location);
      }
  }
  else
  {
      $location = "img/default_pic.jpg";
  }

}
?>
```

Html Code :-

```
<div>
  <?php
  $location = (empty($location)) ? "img/default_pic.jpg" : $location ;
   echo "<img src='".location."' alt='".."'> ";
   ?>
</div>
```

If it helpful don't forget to marked as answer so another can get correct answer easily.

Good Luck..

Comment: Problem still persists, but the code looks a lot more cleaner. I couldn't quite understand the very last part of your suggestion, the `$location = (empty($location)) ? "img/default_pic.jpg" : $location ;` ? Also, what is the significance of the `0777` in the `mkdir` part?

Comment: mkdir() will create directory if not exist with 0777 (all group) permissions

$location = (empty($location)) ? "img/default_pic.jpg" : $location ; with this we checked that $location have value  if not then it will take default path like 'img/default.jpg'

Comment: One more I want to ask, you code in one page or separate. If in same page then may be there issue of scope variable.

Comment: I edited my answer for you just try this I told you if your page work exactly like this..

Comment: For taking the time to reply, thank you so much. The default picture does display now, but not the uploaded picture. All of my code is on one page. I am going to do a select query to reassign the location variable to the file path recorded in the database.

Comment: see you with other question ... ['}